# Appending empty lists in Python with columns from a .CSV

Tags: python, csv

I'm simply trying to append a list to store the information from a column in the .csv file.  There are two columns, Date and Profit/Loss, I'm trying to store each of these columns as Months and Revenue. I am working on this without the use of Pandas and DataFrames, specifically only with importing os and csv.

```
import os
import csv

Months = []
Revenue = []

csvpath = os.path.join("..","budget_data.csv")

with open(csvpath) as FData:
    csvreader = csv.reader(FData)
    
    
    print(csvreader)
      
    csv_header = next(csvreader)
    #print(csv_header)
    counter = 0
    for row in csvreader:
        #print(row)
        counter = counter + 1
        Months.append([0]) 
        Revenue.append([1])
```

Comment: you have to change this `Months.append([0]) ` to this `Months.append(row[0])`. You are forgot add  `row` before `[0] and [1]` in your `append()`

Answer (score 0):

You can just read your csv with Pandas. And having a DataFrame `df` with columns `Date` and `Profit/Loss`, you just have to select these columns and convert it to lists:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("budget_data.csv")

Months = list(df['Date'])
Revenue = list(df['Profit/Loss'])
```

Comment: This might sound silly, but I have to work this without importing pandas and using DataFrames, that's why I went with FData.

Comment: @Vincent, Thanks to Docker alpine :-(